# How to extract apache phoenix table/view data to a file

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

How can I extract data from an apache phoenix table/view to  CSV/PSV/text?

For ex query:

```
select * from test_view
```

Comment: Use some JDBC client, and save the result. Like DBVisualizer

Comment: You can use the phoenix mapreduce job to do that efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

After connecting to phoenix with sqlline.py:

```
phoenix-sqlline zk4-habsem.lzmf1fzmprtezol2fr25obrdth.jx.internal.cloudapp.net,zk5-habsem.lzmf1fzmprtezol2fr25obrdth.jx.internal.cloudapp.net,zk1-habsem.lzmf1fzmprtezol2fr25obrdth.jx.internal.cloudapp.net:2181:/hbase-unsecure
```

which format do you want exported file

```
!outputformat csv
```

Mension local file path

```
!record data.csv
```

Phoenix query which we want to export into file

```
select * from tableName
!record
!quit
```

File is saved in /home/user/data.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use squirrel to extract the data to local file.
Refer 
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/44350/setting-up-squirrel-and-phoenix-integration.html